# Exclude certain directory from ls

Tags: bash

I need listing the content of directory without folder than start with `_`

```
_folder1
_folder2
folder1
folder2
folder3
```

I have tried with `ls -d */ --ignore='_*/'` and `ls -d */ |grep -v '_*'` but i still see them

Comment: And this `ls -l --ignore="_*"` ? (without the `/`)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of standard UNIX utilities like `ls` are not programming, per se. You may be able to get better help on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: `ls -l --ignore="_*"` work but i need only name of directory, `ls -l` print also user and privilege

Comment: `echo [^_]*` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Using `glob` patterns you can use **negation**:

```
ls [!_]*
```

Or:

```
echo [!_]*
```

Using `extglob` you can do:

```
shopt -s extglob

ls !(_*)
```

Comment: `[!_]*` isn't an extended glob; it's a regular glob with a negated character "range". Did you mean `ls !(_)*`?

Comment: Ah thanks that's right. `ls !(_*)` is the right extglob I believe instead of `ls !(_)*`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with `ls -d */ | grep -v '_/*'`